# toInt error when converting character of string to interger

Tags: programming, esp8266

with the following code:

```
int foo = bar[1].toInt;
```

or

```
int foo = bar[1].toInt();
```

I get this error

```
request for member 'toInt' in '*(bar + 1u)', which is of non-class type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'
```

the context for this is bar is the response from a HTTP client over web sockets

Comment: Why are you trying to call a method on something that isn't an object?

Comment: I am trying to convert a character of a string to an integer https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample

Comment: Then what is `bar`? It must be an array of `String` objects then, otherwise this doesn't work. The error clearly shows that you have something like `uint8_t* bar;`. Are you trying to convert a single character to a int, i.e. something in the range of `'0'` to `'9'`?

Comment: 'bar' is the web sockets response (payload). this is generated by the arduino web sockets library https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets (i am basing most of my code on this example https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/master/examples/WebSocketServer_LEDcontrol/WebSocketServer_LEDcontrol.ino)

Comment: Can you use atoi() ?

Comment: using this code `int foo=atoi(payload[1]);` i get this error `invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]` using this code     `int bar=payload[1].atoi;` i get this error `request for member 'atoi' in '*(payload + 1u)', which is of non-class type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'`

Comment: It has to be `int foo=atoi((char*)payload[1]);`. And are you sure about the index `1`, meaning the second character of the payload?

Comment: The question is meaningless without knowing what datatype `bar` is.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino function `toInt` requires a `String` object.
You're passing it a single character, not a `String`.

```
int foo = String(bar[1]).toInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clean on what you are trying to do.  So lets assume the String has "abc123" in and you want the numeric part.

```
const String input = "abc123";
const int foo = input.toInt();  // This will not work!    

const String input = "abc123";
const String tmp = input.substring(3); // Take the end of the string
const int foo = input.toInt();  // foo == 123

const String input = "abc123";
const String tmp = input.substring(3,4); // Take the end of the string
const int foo = input.toInt();  // foo == 1 or 12 (can't quite tell from the docs)
```

Is one of those what you want to do?

You can't take a character and then apply a function from the string class to it without making it a String first.

```
int foo = String(bar[1]).toInt();  // This should work
```

Comment: You mean `.toInt()`?

Comment: I thought I did then I read the original question again.  I don't know about these new fangled String classes.  If its not a uchar I don't use it :)  Corrected post.